# Using AT&T inline assembler for GCC

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm writing a simple but a little specific program:

**Purpose:**  calculate number from it's factorial 
 **Requirements:**  all calculations must be done on gcc inline asm (at&t syntax)

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        unsigned n = 0, f = 0;

        std::cin >> n;

        asm
        (
                "mov %0, %%eax \n"
                "mov %%eax, %%ecx \n"
                "mov 1, %%ebx \n"
                "mov 1, %%eax \n"
                "jmp cycle_start\n"
                "cycle:\n"
                "inc %%ebx\n"
                "mul %%ebx\n"
                "cycle_start:\n"
                "cmp %%ecx, %%eax\n"
                "jnz cycle\n"
                "mov %%ebx, %1 \n":

                "=r" (n):
                 "r" (f)

       );

       std::cout << f;

       return 0;
}
```

This code causes SIGSEV.

Identic program on intel asm syntax (http://pastebin.com/2EqJmGAV) works fine. Why my "AT&T program" fails and how can i fix it?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   unsigned n = 0, f = 0;

   std::cin >> n;

   __asm
   {
      mov eax, n

      mov ecx, eax
      mov eax, 1
      mov ebx, 1
      jmp cycle_start

      cycle:

      inc ebx
      mul ebx

      cycle_start:

      cmp eax, ecx
      jnz cycle

      mov f, ebx
   };
   std::cout << f;

   return 0;
}
```

UPD: Pushing to stack and restoring back used registers gives the same result: SIGSEV

Comment: I'm no inline-assembler expert, but don't you have to tell the compiler which registers you're using so that it can protect those?

Comment: In MSVC i definitly not. I tried to save used registers to stack and restore it. Result was the same - SIGSEV. And don't tell me i can't use stack =)

Comment: @quizzer: GCC has different requirements than MSVC in terms of preserving registers in an inline assembly block (or notifying the compiler of what registers you don't preserve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully there are no requirements to use nothing but gcc inline asm to figure it out. You can translate your AT&T example with `nasm`, then disassemble with `objdump` and see what's the right syntax.

I seem to recall that `mov 1,%eax` should be `mov $1,%eax` if you mean literal constant and not a memory reference.

An answer by @MatsPetersson is very useful regarding the interaction of your inline assembly with the compiler (clobbered/input/output registers). I've focused on the reason why you get `SIGSEGV`, and reading the address `1` does answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

You have your input and output the wrong way around.

So, start by altering

```
            "=r" (n):
             "r" (f)
```

to:

```
             "=r" (f) :
             "r" (n)
```

Then I suspect you'll want to tell the compiler about clobbers (registers you are using that aren't inputs or outputs):

So add:

```
  : "eax", "ebx", "ecx"
```

after the two lines above.

I personally would make some other changes:

1. Use local labels (`1:` and `2:` etc), which allows the code to be duplicated without "duplicate label".
2. Use `%1` instead of `%%ebx` - that way, you are not using an extra register.
3. Move `%0` directly to `%%ecx`. You are loading `1` into `%%eax` two instructions later, so what purpose has it got to do in `%%eax`?

[Now, I'ver written too much, and someone else has answered first... ]

Edit: And, as Anton points out, you need `$1` to load the constant 1, `1` means read from address 1, which doesn't work well, and most likely is the cause of your problems

Comment: Except it's not needed in the other version of the code either, is it now?